# PHP: Getting entire path of a file selected in a file select dialog/window

Tags: php, csv, file-io, import

What I want to be able to do is using PHP allow the user to select a .csv file via a file select dialog/window and then I want to import the data from that file and inset it into my database.

What I need some help with is how do I create the file select window/dialog. I want it so that only .csv files are shown in the file explorer.

any help on how to import the data from the csv after the user has selected the file would also be appreciated. THis is all using PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by "all using PHP"? Aren't you going to have a HTML-based webpage?

Comment: no. I'm doing this for a friend who already has a front end

Comment: Then you'll be receiving the file as part of the request. The file dialog is not the concern of your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
/****** PHP Script *****/
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

         $filename = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
         $filesize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
         $filetype = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
         $filetemp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

         *** do insert using $filename
     }

    /******* html script *****/
    <form action='filename.php' action='post'>
      <input type='file' name='myfile' />     // File browser
      <input type='submit' name='submit' />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the `<input>` `accept` attribute to change the file dialog but browser support varies.  You will need to check the file type and extension once it is uploaded.

[`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) is quite useful for parsing csv files.